# Model Binding in List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding

I have a list inside ViewModel but when I make the Post to the Controller it's not binding it and shows an error on Parameter: null, Value: Null.

If you could help me out on this.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class OperaRateImportRuleViewModel
{
    public SelectList ResortsSelectList { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Resorts")]
    public List<string> ListResort { get; set; }

    public List<Rules> ExtraRuleList { get; set; }


    public OperaRateImportRuleViewModel()
    {
        ExtraRuleList = new List<Rules>();

        ListResort = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EditRules(string id)
    {
        OperaRateImportRuleViewModel model = new OperaRateImportRuleViewModel();
        var getRulesForResort = service.GetAllOperaRateRules().Where(x => x.ResortCode == id).ToList();
        foreach (var item in getRulesForResort)
        {
            var ruleModel = new Rules()
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                IsReferenceRule = item.IsReferenceRule,
                PercentVariation = item.PercentVariation == null ? 0 : Decimal.Round(item.PercentVariation.Value, 2),
                RateCode = item.RateCode,
                ResortCode = item.ResortCode,
                RoomType = item.RoomType,
                SingleRoomDifference = item.SingleRoomDifference == null ? 0 : Decimal.Round(item.SingleRoomDifference.Value, 2),
                SupplementValue = item.SupplementValue == null ? 0 : Decimal.Round(item.SupplementValue.Value, 2)
            };
            model.ExtraRuleList.Add(ruleModel);
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditRules(OperaRateImportRuleViewModel model)
    {
        foreach (var item in model.ExtraRuleList)
        {
            var rule = service.GetAllOperaRateRules().Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            rule.RateCode = item.RateCode;
            rule.ResortCode = item.ResortCode;
            rule.RoomType = item.RoomType;
            rule.PercentVariation = item.PercentVariation;
            rule.SupplementValue = item.SupplementValue;
            rule.SingleRoomDifference = item.SingleRoomDifference;
            rule.IsReferenceRule = item.IsReferenceRule;
            service.Edit(rule);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ManageRules");
    }
```

**And finally my View:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExtraRuleList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ExtraRuleList[i].Id)
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
         <div class="form-group">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].ResortCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].ResortCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].RoomType, new { @class = "form-control" })
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].PercentVariation, new { @class = "form-control textBoxSize" })
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].SupplementValue, new { @class = "form-control textBoxSize" })
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].SingleRoomDifference, new { @class = "form-control textBoxSize" })
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
             <div class="form-group">
                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExtraRuleList[i].IsReferenceRule, new { @class = "checkbox-label" })
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ExtraRuleList[i].IsReferenceRule)
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <span id="deleteSeason" title="Delete" onclick="$(this).closest('.row').remove().trigger(review());" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger row-action"></span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
}
<input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
<a href="javascript:window.history.back()" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
```

**Error**:
[Error when Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9bOj.png)

Much appreciated!

Thanks :)

**EDIT**
**ViewModel Rules:**

```
 public class Rules
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Rate Code")]
    public string RateCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Resort Code")]
    public string ResortCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Room Type")]
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Percent Variation")]
    public decimal? PercentVariation { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Supplement Value")]
    public decimal? SupplementValue { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Single Room Difference")]
    public decimal? SingleRoomDifference { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("")]
    public bool IsReferenceRule { get; set; }

    public string HotelString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The view looks ok to me. Is the for each for the rule list wrapped in a form?

Comment: I assume binding only fails if your click the 'Delete' button (span)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it fails when i press the submit button

Comment: @Wheels73 yes, the binding does not work in the for each...

Comment: Yes, but did you click in a 'Delete' before submitting? The code you have shown works fine (bit would not bind correctly if you removed a row)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i didn't clicked the "Delete" before submitting

Comment: The what is the actual error your getting and which line of code throws it (and as a side note, you code will fail if you do click the 'Delete' button)

Comment: Yes... but are you wrapped in a form... e.g.  @using (Html.BeginForm(

Comment: @StephenMuecke i edit the post with a picture with the error

Comment: Is that error not referring to "DisplayName" which is the ListResort property which is not being catered for in the VIew?

Comment: @Wheels73 i have removed the property but still get the same error

Comment: You now need to bind to the ListResort in the view?

Comment: @Wheels73 binding the ListResort in the view returns the same error. If i comment the for each loop the bind works correctly, but with the for each don't...

Comment: I see nothing in your code which would cause that error (it being thrown when the `ValidationContext` is being created. Can you show the model for `Rules` including the attributes for its properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited the post. i thought i have show it lol

Comment: Remove `[DisplayName("")]` on the `IsReferenceRule` property (or include a value - e.g. `[DisplayName("Is reference rule")]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's it, oh god.. i feel so dumb right now.
Thanks mate :) Cheers

Comment: In any case, you should be using `Display(Name = "....")]` (not `the `DisplayNameAttribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is thrown because your `IsReferenceRule` property is decorated with `[DisplayName("")]`. You need to either delete it, or give it a value, for example

```
[DisplayName("Is Reference Rule ")]
public bool IsReferenceRule { get; set; }
```

but in any case, you should be using the `DisplayAttribute`, not the `DisplayNameAttribute`

```
[Display(Name = "Is Reference Rule ")]
```

---

Specifically, the error occurs when the `public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)` method of `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` is called. The offending line in the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelValidator.cs) is `context.DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName();` which returns `null` because of the missing value in the attribute.